# Spring API to unzip files

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I know  Spring has MultipartFile component.

I am wondering if there is any API to unzip files or read zip files to do some processing?

I have a zip file that following a certain format.

photos\
audio\
report.xml

when the user upload it via web, I wish to scan the zip file and do some processing.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of Java SE APIs for reading ZIP files:

- [`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) - gives you a one-pass reader
- [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) - gives you a reader that allows you to read the entries and the files in any order.

You should be able to use one or the other of these, depending on the nature of your processing.

If the processing requires the images to be in actual files, you would have to create the directories and write the files yourself.  In this case, it would probably be simpler to use an external command to do the ZIP extraction.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know spring have any such type of API,

but you can use other API for ZIP or UNZIP files.

1) http://commons.apache.org/compress/

2) java.util.zip

and also see
[What is a good Java library to zip/unzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files)