# How to download and extract a ZIP file in Java

Tags: java, installation, zip

Ok so I am making a program that I want to look professional, so I'm making an installer for it. What I want to do is make a file on say mediafire or my website and it be a ZIP file. Now what I want to do is extract the folder in the ZIP file to my Program File (x86). How would I do this?

Comment: Does this app. have a GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking into the same thing not too long ago, have a look at [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php). I found this answer from another poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files).

```
public static void unzip(){
    String source = "some/compressed/file.zip";
    String destination = "some/destination/folder";
    String password = "password";

    try {
         ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
         if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword(password);
         }
         zipFile.extractAll(destination);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the link to zip4j is broken

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for ZipInputStream. Try to look here :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/