# How to fix Wget from making a corrupted file in java

Tags: java, terminal, zip, wget, corruption

I'm trying to create an installer for the java program it's supposed to download a zip file from a URL. to do this I'm using the Wget command to download the files in a specific directory. I made it so the code prints out the command it's executing so I can copy and paste it to test. When I test the command it works perfectly, but when I run the code to do it automatically it corrupts the zip file. it won't unzip, and if i transfer the file to my mac it says `Unable to expand filename.zip it is an unsupported file` I believe this is because the file is corrupted.

This is the command it runs

`wget -O /home/pi/1.2.1.zip https://install.swiftpcb.tech/1.2.1.zip`
`unzip /home/pi/1.2.1.zip -d /home/pi`

this is the output of running the unzip one manually

```
Archive:  1.2.1.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zip file, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case, the central directory and zip file comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 1.2.1.zip or
        1.2.1.zip.zip, and cannot find 1.2.1.zip.ZIP, period.
```

this is the class running the command in java (you only need to focus what in the if statement `ran == 0`

```
package Installer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // SQLite connection string
        String url = new Info().getConfigDir();

        // SQL statement for creating a new table
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appInfo (\n"
                + " \"ID\" INTEGER,\n"
                + " \"version\" TEXT,\n"
                + " \"ran\" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,\n"
                + " PRIMARY KEY(\"ID\" AUTOINCREMENT) \n"
                + ");";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            stmt.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        SQLite lite = new SQLite();

        lite.createData();
        int versionChangeStatus = lite.updateVersionInDB();

        if(versionChangeStatus != 0) System.out.println("Something went wrong");

        int ran = lite.getRanValue();

        if(ran == 0){
            String version = new Info().getVersion();
            //for deploy
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget -O /home/pi/" + version + ".zip " + "https://install.swiftpcb.tech/" + version + ".zip" + " && unzip /home/pi/" + version + ".zip -d /home/pi");
            System.out.println("wget -O /home/pi/" + version + ".zip " + "https://install.swiftpcb.tech/" + version + ".zip" + " | unzip /home/pi/" + version + ".zip -d /home/pi");
            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("unzip /home/pi/1.2.1.zip -d /home/pi");
//            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget https://install.swiftpcb.tech/" + version + ".zip" + " && unzip" + version + ".zip -d /home/pi ");

            int updateStat = lite.updateRanValue("1");
            if(updateStat != 0) System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a platform-dependent installer and it may fail when after 2sec without connection, you can try to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461910/how-to-download-and-extract-a-zip-file-in-java

Comment: @rostIvan i fixed it by just downloading the file directly with java using a lib i didn't add that as an answer cause thats not a solution to my problem just a better way of doing it if that makes sense