# Zip extractAll undefined?

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to unzip this file using Java.I found this guide: [What is a good Java library to zip/unzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files) But I'm getting an error: The method extractAll(String) is undefined for the type ZipFile

Code:

```
String dir = System.getProperty(user.dir);
String source = dir+"/file.zip";
                String destination = dir;

                try {
                    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);    
                    zipFile.extractAll(destination);
               } catch (ZipException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

EDIT: I found the solution. It's rather embarrassing, but I imported the wrong one -.-

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: @SašaŠijak I'm just using the code like he did, and Daniel that's the whole error message.

Comment: We can't know if you if you are "using the code like he did".  The imports are important here because zip4j as well as the java libraries themselves contain a `ZipFile` class.

Comment: @user2966573 Can you post whole source code for this

Answer (score 1):

See to it that you have the right jar
http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

I just extracted the jar there is a method in ZipFile.class

```
  public void extractAll(String destPath)
    throws ZipException
  {
    extractAll(destPath, null);
  }
```

So please check that you have proper import from proper jar file, that all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at source code of [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php) (version 1.3.1). The method extractAll definitely exists. Make sure that the zip4j-jar is on your classpath and that you are using the latest version.

Comment: I downloaded the one from the website, how do I add it to my classpath?

Comment: Ok apparently I already have it in my classpath, but I'm still receiving the error o.O