# Java: any way to get a ZipFile (or anything with a direct getEntry method) from a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, zip

I have the contents of a zip file in a byte array.  The file contains a number of entries (typically about 12), but I only care about three of them.

I would like to somehow get this into a `ZipFile` object, so I can pull those specific three `ZipEntry`s out using `ZipFile.getEntry`.  I'm open to using something other than `ZipFile` that has a similar look-up-by-name method like `getEntry`.

My initial investigation suggests that I'm out of luck. `ZipFile` requires a real file in the file subsystem (which I cannot and do not want to access) and so I can't get there from here, and no means other than `ZipFile` exists that allows extracting particular entries by name; but I wanted to check.  In languages like C# and Python, this is pretty straightforward (in C# I go from byte array to `MemoryStream` to `ZipArchive`; in Python I just wrap it in `StringIO` and treat like a file), so I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

My Plan B is to use `ZipInputStream` and repeated calls to `getNextEntry` to go through all dozen or so entries, and throw away all except the three I care about, but that just smells bad to me.

Comment: Personally, "Plan B" is the way to go.  Iterating through the `ZipEntries` isn't that expensive, as the information required to built is maintained within a separate "header" section of the data

Comment: Just use ZipInputStream and it's kin.  Or, if you want a modest challenge, you can write a whole new [PKZIP](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) package in Java.  I've done it twice in C and I don't see how doing it in Java would be so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ZipInputStream` can be instantiated for any `InputStream` ... including a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Apart from that you are out of luck ... if you stick with Java SE classes.

The root of the problem (from an API design perspective) is that ZipFile is a wrapper for functionality that is implemented in native code.  The native code opens the input stream for itself, and it uses a native filename / pathname.

The main reason for a native ZIP implementation that works that way is that the JVM needs to load code from ZIP files as part of the bootstrap procedures.  This happens *before* the native implementation has loaded classes such as `InputStream`.  Indeed, it has to.

There are a number of 3rd party libraries. Start by reading this Q&A - [What is a good Java library to zip/unzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files)