# How to unzip a .ear file using java??

Tags: java, ear

I am trying to extract the contents of .ear file into another file. Is there any existing library which helps me to achieve this?

Comment: Asking for libraries is explicitly off topic.

Comment: An ear file is just a zip fie. Use the Java zip API

Comment: replace .zip with .ear in the filename string http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/programmatically-extract-a-zip-file-using-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good Java library to zip/unzip files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

jar, war, and ear files are all just zip files with a different extension.  As such, they can be processed with the classes in the java.util.zip package that comes with the SDK.