# Unzip in assets Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, xml, zip, unzip

**Objective:**
My goal is to extract a zip in the local folder of the "Assets" application from a button, then verify that the files are there and read them.
I need it to be in java to compile in Android Studio.

Comment: `in the local folder of the "Assets" application` ??? What would that be?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6piFW.png

Comment: You could use some unzip libraries 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files

Comment: you could use your installation folder created by the app installed by the OS like  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/"+yourpackagename+"/Assets/". This will let you delete all files when you uninstall the app